# How padding works in elf file

Tags: elf, readelf

I know the relationship between the virtual address and the file offset in an ELF file

```
VirtAddr = Offset + k * Allin
```

and I know it is due to page dimension (0x1000 in a x86 architecture).
First question:

1. Which is the page dimension in a x64 architecture? Is it 0x200000 or can be lower?

Moving on, if I try `readelf -lW /bin/ls`, I obtain the following information:

```
Elf file type is DYN (Shared object file)
Entry point 0x56d0
There are 9 program headers, starting at offset 64

Program Headers:
  Type           Offset   VirtAddr           PhysAddr           FileSiz  MemSiz   Flg Align
  PHDR           0x000040 0x0000000000000040 0x0000000000000040 0x0001f8 0x0001f8 R E 0x8
  INTERP         0x000238 0x0000000000000238 0x0000000000000238 0x00001c 0x00001c R   0x1
      [Requesting program interpreter: /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2]
  LOAD           0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x01e4e8 0x01e4e8 R E 0x200000
  LOAD           0x01f390 0x000000000021f390 0x000000000021f390 0x001278 0x002570 RW  0x200000
  DYNAMIC        0x01fdd8 0x000000000021fdd8 0x000000000021fdd8 0x0001f0 0x0001f0 RW  0x8
  NOTE           0x000254 0x0000000000000254 0x0000000000000254 0x000044 0x000044 R   0x4
  GNU_EH_FRAME   0x01afa0 0x000000000001afa0 0x000000000001afa0 0x000884 0x000884 R   0x4
  GNU_STACK      0x000000 0x0000000000000000 0x0000000000000000 0x000000 0x000000 RW  0x10
  GNU_RELRO      0x01f390 0x000000000021f390 0x000000000021f390 0x000c70 0x000c70 R   0x1

 Section to Segment mapping:
  Segment Sections...
   00     
   01     .interp 
   02     .interp .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id .gnu.hash .dynsym .dynstr .gnu.version .gnu.version_r .rela.dyn .rela.plt .init .plt .plt.got .text .fini .rodata .eh_frame_hdr .eh_frame 
   03     .init_array .fini_array .data.rel.ro .dynamic .got .got.plt .data .bss 
   04     .dynamic 
   05     .note.ABI-tag .note.gnu.build-id 
   06     .eh_frame_hdr 
   07     
   08     .init_array .fini_array .data.rel.ro .dynamic .got
```

And with the command `readelf -SW /bin/ls`

```
There are 29 section headers, starting at offset 0x20748:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            0000000000000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .interp           PROGBITS        0000000000000238 000238 00001c 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 2] .note.ABI-tag     NOTE            0000000000000254 000254 000020 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 3] .note.gnu.build-id NOTE            0000000000000274 000274 000024 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 4] .gnu.hash         GNU_HASH        0000000000000298 000298 0000b4 00   A  5   0  8
  [ 5] .dynsym           DYNSYM          0000000000000350 000350 000d20 18   A  6   1  8
  [ 6] .dynstr           STRTAB          0000000000001070 001070 0005f6 00   A  0   0  1
  [ 7] .gnu.version      VERSYM          0000000000001666 001666 000118 02   A  5   0  2
  [ 8] .gnu.version_r    VERNEED         0000000000001780 001780 000070 00   A  6   1  8
  [ 9] .rela.dyn         RELA            00000000000017f0 0017f0 001350 18   A  5   0  8
  [10] .rela.plt         RELA            0000000000002b40 002b40 000a80 18  AI  5  24  8
  [11] .init             PROGBITS        00000000000035c0 0035c0 000017 00  AX  0   0  4
  [12] .plt              PROGBITS        00000000000035e0 0035e0 000710 10  AX  0   0 16
  [13] .plt.got          PROGBITS        0000000000003cf0 003cf0 000018 08  AX  0   0  8
  [14] .text             PROGBITS        0000000000003d10 003d10 012459 00  AX  0   0 16
  [15] .fini             PROGBITS        000000000001616c 01616c 000009 00  AX  0   0  4
  [16] .rodata           PROGBITS        0000000000016180 016180 004e1d 00   A  0   0 32
  [17] .eh_frame_hdr     PROGBITS        000000000001afa0 01afa0 000884 00   A  0   0  4
  [18] .eh_frame         PROGBITS        000000000001b828 01b828 002cc0 00   A  0   0  8
  [19] .init_array       INIT_ARRAY      000000000021f390 01f390 000008 08  WA  0   0  8
  [20] .fini_array       FINI_ARRAY      000000000021f398 01f398 000008 08  WA  0   0  8
  [21] .data.rel.ro      PROGBITS        000000000021f3a0 01f3a0 000a38 00  WA  0   0 32
  [22] .dynamic          DYNAMIC         000000000021fdd8 01fdd8 0001f0 10  WA  6   0  8
  [23] .got              PROGBITS        000000000021ffc8 01ffc8 000038 08  WA  0   0  8
  [24] .got.plt          PROGBITS        0000000000220000 020000 000398 08  WA  0   0  8
  [25] .data             PROGBITS        00000000002203a0 0203a0 000268 00  WA  0   0 32
  [26] .bss              NOBITS          0000000000220620 020608 0012e0 00  WA  0   0 32
  [27] .gnu_debuglink    PROGBITS        0000000000000000 020608 000034 00      0   0  4
  [28] .shstrtab         STRTAB          0000000000000000 02063c 00010a 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings), I (info),
  L (link order), O (extra OS processing required), G (group), T (TLS),
  C (compressed), x (unknown), o (OS specific), E (exclude),
  l (large), p (processor specific)
```

The last section present in the `LOAD (R E)` segment is `.eh_frame`; the first section in `LOAD (R W)` segment is `.init_array`.

In the ELF file there is a lot of zeros between the two sections `hexdump -C /bin/ls`

```
0001e4d0  10 00 00 00 7c 2c 00 00  68 7c ff ff 29 00 00 00  |....|,..h|..)...|
0001e4e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
*
0001f390  d0 57 00 00 00 00 00 00  90 57 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.W.......W......|
0001f3a0  b0 63 00 00 00 00 00 00  f0 6a 00 00 00 00 00 00  |.c.......j......|
```

2. Why there are a lot of zeros between these two sections?

I don't think it is linked to the page: if its file offset was  (for example) 0x1f100 instead of 0x1f390 it should works well.

In that case its Virtual Address should be 0x21f100, thus respecting the congruence law

What's wrong with my interpretation?